# trying to +1 to random.seed() for every loop

Tags: python, random, methods, while-loop

I'm working on a casino program that gets a bet ($1-$50) from the user, then pulls a slot machine to display a three-string combination of "7", "cherries", "bar", or "(space)". Certain combinations will trigger a bet multiplier, and the user will win back this amount. The run should look like this: ask user for bet, show user the pull and their winnings, then ask user for a new bet, display a new pull, and so on.

Right now, I have everything down except for a couple problems - I cannot make it so that the program generates a new random combination for each pull. Secondly, the main loop continues forever, printing the user's pull and winnings forever. Below is the method that generates either "7", "cherries", etc.

```
def rand_string(self):
    random.seed(0)
    # produces a number between 0 and 999
    test_num = random.randrange(1000)

    # precompute cutoffs
    bar_cutoff = 10 * TripleString.BAR_PCT
    cherries_cutoff = bar_cutoff + 10 * TripleString.CHERRIES_PCT
    space_cutoff = cherries_cutoff + 10 * TripleString.SPACE_PCT

    # bar = 38%, cherries = 40%, space = 7%, seven = 15%
    if test_num < bar_cutoff:
        return TripleString.BAR
    elif test_num < cherries_cutoff:
        return TripleString.CHERRIES
    elif test_num < space_cutoff:
        return TripleString.SPACE
    else:
        return TripleString.SEVEN
```

And here is the loop in main:

```
while(True):
if bet == 0: #a bet of $0 ends the program
    print("Please come again!")
    break
else:
    print("whirrr...and your pull is " +\
          object.pull())
    object.display(None)
```

I thought I could solve this by somehow adding 1 to random.seed() for each loop (we begin with random.seed(0), but for each new pull 1 is added so that random.seed(1) and so on), but I don't know how to go about doing this and I'm not even sure if it's doable. If someone could point out my mistakes here, that'd be great. (sorry if this makes no sense, I'm very new to Python).

Comment: I think your understanding of `seed` is off. There is no need to set a seed for this, just keep drawing random numbers

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `random.seed(0)` once in the program. By seeding every time you are reseting the pseudo random number generator and forcing it to produce the same number.

```
random.seed(0)
while(True):
if bet == 0: #a bet of $0 ends the program
...
```

You can read more about random seeding [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed).

Comment: Or just not set a seed at all? I can't see what its purpose is in this application.

Comment: @roganjosh So that you get different random numbers each time you start your program.

Comment: You'd get that without setting a seed. I don't see any need to _guarantee_ that you set the RND in a different state each time. Even from a single seed you could keep drawing more numbers